# output image is black in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, fileoutputstream

I first tried to convert jpg into array of rgb values and then tried to revert same array into jpg

```
picw = selectedImage.getWidth();
pich = selectedImage.getHeight();

int[] pix = new int[picw * pich];

selectedImage.getPixels(pix, 0, picw, 0, 0, picw, pich);
int R, G, B;

for (int y = 0; y < pich; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < picw; x++) {
            int index = y * picw + x;
            R = (pix[index] >> 16) & 0xff;
            G = (pix[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
            B = pix[index] & 0xff;
            pix[index] = (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;
        }
    }
```

Untill this point all things are fine(i checked by Loging the array), but when i create bitmap to compress it in jpg, the output is of black image.

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(pix, picw, pich,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File file = new File(folder,"Wonder.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me to move Further, Thanks

Comment: You seem to be missing one byte of data for each pixel: alpha.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek ,Please will you explain me in more detail , i dont know about this.

Comment: Alpha controls how much the pixel is visible, from 0 (not visible) to 255 (fully visible, or opaque). When you are changing the pixel with `pix[index] = (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;` you leave the value for alpha as 0.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek , so how i can add this Alpha in this code.

Comment: you can google for [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) format

Answer (score 0):

First let me explain how this data is stored per pixel:

Each pixel has 32bits of data to store a value for: Alpha, Red, Green and Blue. Each of these values is just 8 bits (or a byte). (there are a lot of other formats to store color information, but the one you specified is `ARGB_8888`).

In this format, white is `0xffffffff` and black is `0xff000000`.

So, like i said in the comments, the alpha seems to be missing. A red pixel without any alpha like `0x00ff0000` is not going to be visible.

Alpha can be added by first storing it:

```java
A = (pix[index] >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Although the value is probably going to be 255 (because JPEG doesn't have alpha), i think it would be wise to use it like this in case you decide to use another format that does have alpha.

Then you should put the alpha back in:

```java
pix[index] = (A << 24) | (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;
```

This should write the exact same value to `pix[index]` which it already contains, not changing anything. But it will leave you with the original image instead of just black.